# How can I listen for left mouseclicks on a canvas in a C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent

I am trying to listen for a mouse click anywhere on my window (Except for the locations where the buttons are, but I'll deal with that later) and then return the point (x,y) of the location.

here is the relevant code:

```
 private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("mouseLeft is clicked");
    Point x = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this);
    Console.WriteLine(x.X);
    Console.WriteLine(x.Y);
}

<Canvas MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
```

When I click, nothing is printed. What am I doing wrong exactly? The first method is inside mainWindow.Xaml.cs.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Set background to transparent and set size of canvas!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes things won't be written to the console correctly in GUI Apps, try using Debug.WriteLine, MessageBox.Show, or settings a breakpoint to see if the event is being fired.

The code you have there looks perfectly fine.

Comment: I just used messagebox.show, no luck. The method isn't being called.

Comment: Is there anything in your canvas or is it blank?

Comment: I have 3 buttons, but it is blank aside from that.

Comment: Ok, that is the problem then. With WPF controls have to have some visible part that differs from whatever is behind it to be able to be clicked. If you set a background color on your canvas that differs from the color behind it you should get the click events.